# Error This line has a length of 182. Maximum allowed is 100 max-len

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

In my `App.vue` file, when a blank space remains, it failed to compile and the error shows on by browser:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/App.vue Module Error (from
>   ./node_modules/eslint-loader/index.js):
>
> E:\NodeJS...\src\App.vue   5:1  error  This line has a length of 182.
>   Maximum allowed is 100  max-len
>
> ✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

My code on App.vue is

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-view/>
</div>
</template>
```

How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's just as the error says. You have a line that's too long (but you haven't posted any code...)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have edited the post. Please take a look.

Comment: So, yes, you do have a line that's way too long. Have you tried splitting it up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just break line 5 so that it is readable and goes on multiple lines

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" 
    data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria- 
    controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle 
    navigation"
  >
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-view/>
</div>
</template>
```

Comment: It's also possible to adjust the es-lint rule: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/max-len, but in this particular case I'd agree with Mukund, split the line up